# For loop or Lambda function?

Tags: python

I have this two code, they both (only the first right now) should return me the lenght of sequence that is repeated (13, 6, 6, 14, 6 AND 13, 6, 6, 14, 6):

```
l = [13, 6, 6, 14, 6, 13, 6, 6, 14, 6]

def count_period(l): 
    
    l_max = int((len(l)/2)+1)

    for i in range(2, l_max):
        interval1 = l[0:i] 
        intervallo2 = l[i:2*i]
        if interval1 == interval2:
            return i
```

And:

```
l = [13, 6, 6, 14, 6, 13, 6, 6, 14, 6]

l_max = int((len(l)/2)+1)
period_value= next(filter(lambda x: [l[0:x] == l[x:2*x] in range(2, l_max)], l), None)
```

Why the first code return the right value (5) while the second return me 13? What I'm doing wrong? About this topic: since I'm newbie to Python from a general point of view (and not about this case), how I can know which path should i follow to get a good code (with low execution time and low cyclomatic complexity)? For example  in this case (let us assume that I haven't written anything yet), which of this two way (or another) should I follow? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be filtering `range(2, l_max)` not `l` to translate your code from the top into a filter. Right now for each value in `l` you are creating a list in the predicate lamdba you define filter to use. If that list has items in it it returns `true`, only the empty list would return `false`. Filter then decides to keep the value `x` if it passes the predicate or discards it if it does not. So therefore it keeps all items in the original list and `next` on that list is 13. You should do this instead:

```
l = [13, 6, 6, 14, 6, 13, 6, 6, 14, 6]

l_max = int((len(l)/2)+1)
period_value= next(filter(lambda x: l[0:x] == l[x:2*x], range(2, l_max)), None)
```